# jQuery: Click event with two functions

Tags: jquery, css

I have a box with a headbar-div and a content-div and I created a script which can toggle the content-div with a slide effect. 
Normally the headbar-div has a background-color #ccc but when I toggle the content away the background-color of the headbar-div should be #FFF;
And after that, if I let the content be shown again the background-color should change again to #ccc.

With my code the problem is that if I click again the background-color doesn't change back

**Script**

```
$( ".togglepanelcontent" ).click(function() {
    var icon = $( this );
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelcontent" ).slideToggle();
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelheadbar" ).addClass("panelheadbar_m");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="module" class="panelgroup">
    <div class="panelheadbar">Title<div class="togglepanelcontent"><span>-</span></div></div>
    <div id="pc" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">
        Text
    </div>
<br>
```

**CSS**

```
.togglepanelcontent {
    float: right; cursor: pointer;
}
.panelheadbar {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    cursor: move;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.panelheadbar_m {
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
.panelheadbar_m:hover { 
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}
.panelcontent {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 10px; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: The counterpart to `.addClass("panelheadbar_m")` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are slideToggling, you need to `toggleClass` too!

Replace the following in your code:

```
icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelheadbar" ).addClass("panelheadbar_m");
```

With this:

```
icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelheadbar" ).toggleClass("panelheadbar_m");
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. :) I can accept the answer in 10min